# Can't purchase IAP on iOS with Codemane one

Tags: codenameone

I followed the great tutorial to implements In-App purchases with my CN1 app and it works well on Android.

But on iOS I received this message :

SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing
Transaction error Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Connexion ├á lΓÇÖiTunes Store impossible" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Connexion ├á lΓÇÖiTunes Store impossible}

My IAP are "Approved" on iTunes.

Can you help me ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I unchecked "Cleared for Sale" and check it again and after a few hours it works \o/

Comment: IAP takes time to refresh and switching between sandbox/production environments also takes time. It's one of the annoyances of itunes connect